# Arduino OBD library and software serial library

Tags: arduino-uno, softwareserial, uart

Can I use Arduino OBD library with "custom" software serial or it needs to be used with hardware UART only? For example if I have D5 and D6 pin as RX and TX in my code hooked on OBD board, how do I initialize OBD library from there?

This is the [OBD library](https://github.com/stanleyhuangyc/ArduinoOBD) that I'm referring to.

And I'm using this [Allpro OBD](http://www.obddiag.net/allpro.html) board.

**Update**
Actually I would be satisfied with a answer how to know when entire response from the board is received, because this way is way too messy:

```
void getResponse(void){
 while(obdSerial.available()){
   Serial.write(obdSerial.read());
  }
}
```

Here I don't know when the message is received. And if I try to use example from **Sparkfun** **obd-ii-uart-hookup-guide** (different board doe) I ended up in infinite-loop since the board never return `\r`, if I send ELM command to use `\n` as terminator, and if I disable ELM to echo the command so that I use just one `getResponse` call I get some readings, but not all the time, I ended up in infinite-loop again.

Comment: What / where is an Arduino OBD library? What does its documentation say?

Comment: Sorry I have updated my question with links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That library is hard-coded to use the single Hardware Serial device on the Arduino Uno or the second Hardware Serial1 device on other boards.

```
#ifndef OBDUART
#if defined(__AVR_ATmega328P__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega168P__)
#define OBDUART Serial
#else
#define OBDUART Serial1
#endif
#endif
```

You can edit the library's header file `OBD.h` to define your own serial port though:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
extern SoftwareSerial mySerialPort;
#define OBDUART mySerialPort
```

And then in your sketch create the `mySerialPort` SoftwareSerial object.

Comment: I have updated my question again, sorry :) I would really appreciate if you can take another look. But thanks for this one, this is also something that I needed.